# How can I prevent Next JS from preloading child pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using Next JS 13 app directory with firebase. and whenever it loads a parent page it loads all the children as well. but the issue is that when a child page is visited it loads as new page. if it wasn't requesting to the server i maybe okay with it.

let's say i have productsList page with 24 products total. in this page we display all the products. when an item is clicked it redirects to a detail page. so in the initial page it loads 24 reads to a server, and additional 24 reads b/c it is reading the details as well. so that makes it 48 total reads. but the user might select only one or none. but it loads much without necessity. that is a waste of reads.

and when user selects a product it loads as new read. that is an additional read which makes it 49 read.

is there a way to prevent next js to read the child before it is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable prefetching by adding `prefetch={false}` to your `<Link />` components. [Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/link#prefetch)

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
 
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <Link href="/dashboard" prefetch={false}>
      Dashboard
    </Link>
  );
}
```

Comment: does this affect SEO? i mean i used a dynamic metadata, but when prefetch is false it doesn't load the pages. does that mean it won't be visible for SEO? [here is the docs](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/pre-rendering)

Comment: No, it doesn't affect SEO and it will be visible for search engine crawlers. The docs you're linked are unrelated to pre-**fetching**, they concern pre-**rendering**. Pre-fetching is a way to provide a better user experience by fetching data before they navigate there, crawlers will follow links normally.